# OpenCV cascade classifier return different result in C++ and Java version

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

my problem is the detectMultiScale function return different result in C++ and java version. I've tested it in C++(Ubuntu) and java (android). Both use the same parameter and the cascade xml file but with 1 image, C++ version return 2 rects, and java return 4 rects (they also have different value).

```
detectMultiScale(imageInput, resultList, 1.1, 1, 0 | 2 , Size(20, 20), Size(250, 250));
```

I'm try to debug but still have no solution for this. Can any body help me? Thanks,